# If I want to create one of three similar types of cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath, how do I set the "common" properties?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, swift

Say I have three different cell types that look different, but have a few fields that are present in all three, so they all come from the same superclass, say, `Animal`.

But some animals are very different, and that's where the three different types of cells come in. One is maybe for lovable pets which has a unique look, another for lizards, and the third for birds.

I want present the right kind of cell depending on what kind of animal I'm dealing with. So I could just check the animal's `type` property, dequeue the cell, set it up and return it.

But for things like the name and height, all the animals have that and I'd like to set it up centrally without having to do it inside every animal check with repeated code.

So using polymorphism I declared an instance of the parent, then create each subclass and set up the specific properties, then set up the general ones.

```
var cell: AnimalCell
let animal = animals[indexPath.row]

switch animal.type {
    case "cat", "dog":
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PetTableViewCell
    case "lizard":
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LizardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LizardTableViewCell
        cell.scaleAmount = 7
        cell.spikes = true
    default:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BirdCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as BirdTableViewCell
        cell.wings = true
}

cell.animalNameLabel.text = animal.name
cell.animalHeightLabel.text = animal.height
cell.animalSound.text = animal.sound

return cell
```

But I get an error that within the case statements it still thinks that the cells are of type `AnimalCell`, even after I create them with the right kind. So this isn't working.

How would I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I get an error that within the case statements it still thinks that the cells are of type `AnimalCell`

That is because the compiler pays attention only to the *static type* of the `cell`, not to its *run-time type*. The `as` expression changes the type of the object that you assign to `cell`, but it does not change the static type of `cell`. The static type is set by the `var cell: AnimalCell` declaration; assignments to `cell` do not change its static type.

You can fix this by making a local variable of the proper type, setting up its properties through that variable, and then assigning it to `cell` at the end:

```
switch animal.type {
    case "cat", "dog":
        let catOrDog = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PetTableViewCell
        cell = catOrDog
    case "lizard":
        let lizard = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LizardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LizardTableViewCell
        lizard.scaleAmount = 7
        lizard.spikes = true
        cell = lizard
    default:
        let bird = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BirdCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as BirdTableViewCell
        bird.wings = true
        cell = bird
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to set the superclass properties this way, but in order to set the subclass properties, you'll need to do a local type cast. I believe in swift, it would look like:

```
(cell as LizardCell).spikes = true
```

Sorry if that's not quite accurate syntax; I haven't tested it. The logic should still apply, though: you will need to type-cast in order to reference subclass properties. An alternative would be:

```
let lizardCell = cell as LizardCell
lizardCell.spikes = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Ian and dasblinkenlight have correct answers.

An alternate solution would be to create an `animal` property on `AnimalCell`. You could override the setter in each `AnimalCell` subclass to call the super implementation and then take care of its specific animal's properties after that.

This could simplify your table code to

```
let animal = animals[indexPath.row]
let cell: AnimalCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(animal.reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) 
cell.animal = animal
return cell
```

(Of course, a property like `animal.reuseIdentifier` is only one way to get the correct reuse identifier.)

This would also have the benefit of letting you use these table cells in multiple view controllers more easily.